# Database montage is Not accessible

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I am Using SQL server management Studio 2014.

i have Created database  before windows Authentication with out username and password.

can view  all table and stored procedure after that i want  use username and password  now added Security added new login  username and password .

Now i connected same database with  username and password. i can't accessible database(object Explorer) i can't view table. before  i can view table and stored procedure .

How  to fix this issues?   i have tired restart sql server instance  sql server configuration manager . but its connected object Explorer  with created username and password i can't view table.with out username and password . i can views table and stored procedure .

Comment: Have you created a login? Have you cerated a user based upon that login? Have you set permissions for that user within the required database? Can you post the script for the actions you have performed so far?

Comment: Check your user mappings and server roles, are they correct?

Comment: where i check  mappings and server roles? where i  find this?